# Laptop display failure

Tags: display, hardware-failure, hp-pavilion

I have a HP Pavilion g6 1232a, the monitor flickers/turn white when I move the monitor. If I'm lucky I might just get it to show the right things. What is causing this, it can't be the monitor caused it works when at a certain angle.

Answer (score 5):

This is very often the cable that goes 'through' the hinges from the laptop case to the display.

If you are brave and able to open the case you can sometimes get to the connector, which is usually a flat plastic cable with conducting 'tracks' that is just inserted into its receiving end on the motherboard and held there by friction. This means that if the error is *there*, you could try to pull the cable out and put it back in.
Reaching this connector in the display is more difficult.

But, more likely, the cable has a break/tear near the hinges, because it flexes there all the time.

So I really suggest you bring the laptop to a repair shop. They have seen these things before and may be able to replace the cable.